# How can you document a REST API usage/consumption?

Tags: api, rest, workflow, integration

We have a medium size app (100+ SQL tables), and we often need to integrate it with partner APIs (with our system as a client/consumer). Process of designing such integration is non-trivial:

- We often need to map columns in our database to fields in requests to partner API.
- Some fields in requests to partner API must be constant, or conditional
- In rare occasions output from one API response becomes an input to another API request

There are many resources on the web to document REST APIs - there are specific formats for that (Swagger, RAML, etc.). These formats allow efficient generation of client code and human-readable documentation. However these formats are not very helpful for describing how your app integrates with an API. We create lengthy Microsoft Word documents which contain more or less a copy of partner API methods with comments how every individual field should be used. Such solution seems sub-optimal.

Googling for better options did not yield many results, namely Swaggerhub seems to have "comments" functionality which seems to target the problem above and pretty much that's all.

**Question: are there some tools, formats, workflows, ideas, etc. which facilitate designing and documenting API integrations described above?**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which language you use, but i work with ApiDoc

https://apidocjs.com/

He is perfect to generate an API REST doc with comment in NodeJS, he can be used with many language